# Problema para actualizar datos de pagina sin tener que abrirla

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño Dashboard con placas arduino. Hasta ahora todo funciona bien; las placas leen los datos de temperatura y consumo de unos cuartos frios, los envía a mi hosting y puedo ver los datos en tiempo real en mi pagina.

La cuestión es que necesito que cuando se sobrepase cierta temperatura se me envié un mensaje a **Telegram** informando la novedad, todo esto lo he logrado hacer, pero el mensaje me llega siempre y cuando tenga la página abierta como tal, mi idea es que el mensaje llegue sin tener que estar la pagina abierta, no se si me hago entender..

Este es el código con el cual llamo los datos, hago la verificación y llamo la pagina que envía el mensaje:

```js
<script> // generamos alerta cuando la temperatura suba cierta medida
    
    setInterval(function () {
        var JSON=$.ajax({
        url:"https://xxxxxxxxx.com.co/sensores/DatoSensores.php?q=1",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false}).responseText;
        var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
        //var temperatura = Respuesta[0].temperature;
        temperatura = parseFloat(Respuesta[0].temperature); //Leemos la temperatura de json
        humedad = parseFloat(Respuesta[0].humidity); //llemos la humedad del json
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = temperatura;
        
        if(temperatura > 20.30){
            
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com.co/sensores/puntos/mensaje.php',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('body').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);
    
</script>
```

Agradezco me puedan oriental sobre que podría hacer, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, si el envio de temperatura lo controla una webApp... hay que cambiar de sistema. Por que este setInterval que tienes solo funcionará cuando esté activo este front end. Lo que tienes que hacer es que la placa arduino envíe sí o sí los datos al server cada X minutos que a tí te interese. Lo más facil es que lo programes con python y generas un proceso que esté siempre activo. Puedes entonces programar que se inicie siempre que se encienda la placa y etc, así incluso si se va la corriente y vuelve, volverá a activarse la rutina automaticametne. Un saludo.

Comment: Pero la placa arduino si envía los datos de manera constante, el problema radica es en el análisis de la condición para que envie la alerta, es decir es necesario una forma de estar consultando constantemente la base de datos y analizar esa temperatura para genera la alerta, pero de manera "segundo plano" sin tener que estar abriendo la página.

Comment: Estos datos la placa arduino lo envia a MySql?

Comment: Hola de nuevo, entonces el mensaje de alerta tambien puede enviarlo la placa arduino de la misma manera que envía los datos. O también puede hacerlo el servidor en el momento que recibe los datos evaluarlos y decidir si enviar o no el mensaje de alerta. No veo el problema, o es que hay algo que no entiendo bien ? Un saludo.

Comment: Los datos si llegan a MySQL, en cuanto a lo que me cuotas que el servidor puede enviar el mensaje... Si mal no entiendo es que hago hago actualmente pero como lo menciono evalúa y envía el dato siempre tu cuando tenga la página "abierta", por eso era mi pregunta si hay una manera de que ya sea la placa o ya sea el servidor lo haga internamente, sin tener que abrir la página..

Comment: he tratado de hacerlo como me mencionas, directamente desde la placa arduino, pero el monitor serial me bota el siguiente mensaje:           Error al conectar con la API de Telegram
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>                 ,, segun entiendo es por la placa que estoy usando , que es una ethernet shiel y estuve indagando y esta no soporta https.. alli no sabria como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero
Crea un bot de Telegram siguiendo las instrucciones aquí: https://core.telegram.org/bots#3-how-do-i-create-a-bot

asumo que podrias hacerlo en php

puedes usar la api obtniendo un TOKEN
[https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/sendMessage)

```
<?php
// Configura las variables necesarias
$token = "TU_TOKEN_AQUI";
$chat_id = "CHAT_ID_AQUI";
$texto = "Hola, mindillo";

// Envía la solicitud HTTP POST
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage";
$data = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $texto);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "Error al enviar el mensaje.";
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente.";
}
?>
```

Tambien puede proogramar un chron job para correr cada cierto tiempo el script

```
* * * * * php /ruta/a/mi_script.php
```

Si estás en Windows, puedes utilizar el Programador de tareas para programarlo
eso te lo dejo de tarea

Comment: a modo de comentario, el script puede ser el mismo quue llame el arduino asi cada que el arduino llame la pagiina esta analiza la info y manda el mensaje casi casi en tiempo real

Comment: La cuestión es que solo funcionaría cuando tenga la página abierta, lo que se necesita es que se envié el mensaje sin abrir ninguna página.

Comment: te estoy diciendo como se puede hacer sin abrir ninguna pagina, ya que si lo programas en php el server es quien interpreta los datos y envia el mensaje, y la pagina quien la abre el el arduino

Comment: ya habia creado una tarea cron en el servidor del hosting, pero no hace nada.. lo de la tarea programada en windows no logro entenderlo, puesto que al final la placa va a estar conectada solo a la red y a la corriente, no a un pc.

Comment: como haces para que se guarden los datos en la base mysql?

Comment: con un codigo php que recibe los datos desde arduino con GET y los envia a la base de datos, este archivo esta alojado en mi servidor.

Comment: entonces a ese codigo php debes agregarle el codigo para que evalue y mande el mensaje sin tener que abrir ninguna pagina pues el arduino llama a la pagina y activa el codigo en su llamada http por metodo get, entiendes? si lo haces asi nisiquiera es necesario guardarlo en la base, solo si despues quieres revisar el historial o algo por el estilo. y tampoco necesitas la tarea programada pues el codigo se ejecuta cada que el arduino llame la pagina

Comment: La respuesta de Jhon ha sido perfecta, no había caído en cuenta que la pagina con la cual ingreso los datos a mi base de datos, está constantemente siendo "llamada" por el arduino, efectivamente aquí he realizado la validación de cada registro que llega, muchísimas gracias por su ayuda.